# Request log in console for Jetty container using xsbt-web-plugin

Tags: scala, logging, jetty, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm using the `xsbt-web-plugin` to develop a webservice.

For easier debugging I would like to switch on request logs in console like the line below.

> [22/Dez/2012:15:29:56 +0000] "GET /messages HTTP/1.1" 200 27276

In production I'm using `NCSARequestLog` which is fine, but in development I would like to include the log in my `sbt console` where I started the container via `container:start`/

How can I enable the request logs?

Answer (score 1):

To enable request logs, you can configure an `NCSARequestLog` via a custom *jetty.xml* file.

Add this to *build.sbt*:

```
env in Compile := Some(file(".") / "jetty-env.xml" asFile)
```

Create *myproject/jetty-env.xml*:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
      <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
          <Set name="filename"><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/test-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
          <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
          <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
          <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
          <Set name="append">true</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>

</Configure>
```

In sbt, run `container:start`, and you'll see request logs collected under *myproject/logs*.  When I tested this, Jetty would not create the *logs* directory on its own - I had to do that myself.

You can watch the request log in real time with `tail`:

```
tail -f myproject/logs/test-2013_08_23.request.log
```

For a full example of this, see the [*request-logging* branch of xwp-template](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xwp-template/tree/request-logging).